# Dynamically added UserControl does not adjust to parent size

Tags: wpf, xaml, size, fill, contentcontrol

I have a UserControl which will be loaded at runtime into a ContentControl.
The user control does not adjust its size to the parent control even I haven't set Width nor Height. What is it that I miss?

```
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainContentControl" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <Label  Background="LightGray" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >Sample control </Label>
    </ContentControl>
```

The sample control ( label ) inside the ContentControl works just fine and expands depending on size changes of the ContentControl.

When I now replace the Label with an UserControl the size of the Usercontrol has as maxsize the position of the label which is inside it

Here the UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.testUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="235,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your label is aligned to the top left of the container, so it may just look that way.  You should snag Snoop and examine your UI at runtime to see how it's really laid out.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The label in the second code sample is not the problem. The UserControl itself is not fullsize of the parent ContentControl. If I give the Grid a background color ...it shows that it is only colored until the end of the label. The real problem that I have is, I do have in my full code a ListView inside this UserControl and want this to be full width and using the complete height (without changing it's top and left ...). But obviously the UserControl doesn't take the size of it's parent and therefore the children of the usercontrols don't expand either

Comment: ListViews are PITAs about this.  You have to specifically set the [horizontal and vertical content alignments on them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) otherwise their children don't take up all the available space.  Rather than trying to pair down your code, create a [mcve] that reproduces your issue and put that into an [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` which tells WPF *"draw this control with only the size it needs, then align it in the parent container according to these rules"*.

So your label is getting drawn to the exact size it needs, then placed in the Top Left corner.

If your top section of code, you are using `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignement`, which means *"align the content **inside** this control like this"*.

So `HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` would draw the Label according to whatever the parent container's rules are (sounds like in your case `Stretch`), then the content inside the Label would get positioned in the middle.

So either change your Horizonta/VerticalAlignment properties to Horizontal/VerticalContentAlignment, or set the value of them `Stretch`

Comment: Ya, that smells like it.